# Unresolved external symbol for global variable

Tags: c++, windows, linker-errors, dllimport

I've been struggling to understand this issue, hope someone can give me some hints. I have a global variable defined using the nifty counter idiom.

In the header file the definition looks like:

```cpp
BOOST_SYMBOL_EXPORT extern MyClass& GVar;
```

In the source file I have the following:

```cpp
MyClass& GVar = reinterpret_cast<MyClass&>(Buffer);
```

Using GCC on Debian and Ubuntu everything is compiled and linked correctly. On Windows, though, I get the following error when trying to link the DLL to my test executable:

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class MyClass& GVar" (GVAR_MANGLED_NAME)
```

I also checked that the symbol exists in the DLL and it seems to be there, among the exported ones. I don't really know what else to try anymore.

Does anyone have any experience with a problem like this?

Comment: Can you `reinterpret_cast` a reference?

Comment: Yes, that is not a problem.
Check for example here for a standard implementation of the nifty counter https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Nifty_Counter

Comment: Seems kind of excessive, but sure.

Comment: PS I think the problem is that I have to switch between dllexport and dllimport when using the header to locate a symbol of an external DLL. So annoying... I will do some more tests tomorrow, but I think this may solve it

Comment: @Triskeldeian Which compiler at the Windows machine? MSVC or GCC as well? Also linker path setup for DLL runtime linkage and stubs might be relevant information.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ I'm using MSVC 16.8.4
I think the issue is due to the fact I was not switching between dllexport and dllimport. Apparently that's not a problem for classes and functions, but it is a problem for objects. I still don't understand why there is difference but that's what I got ATM

Comment: @Triskeldeian _"I think the issue is due to the fact I was not switching between dllexport and dllimport."_ sounds sound

Answer (score 1):

So the issue was due to this (from [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20140911111411/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/russellk/archive/2005/03/20/399465.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0)):

> __declspec(dllimport) can be used on both code and data, and its semantics are subtly different between the two. When applied to a routine call, it is purely a performance optimization. For data, it is required for correctness. [...] If you export a data item from a DLL, you must declare it with `__declspec(dllimport)` in the code that accesses it. Using `__declspec(dllimport)` is optional on function declarations, but the compiler produces more efficient code if you use this keyword. However, you must use `__declspec(dllimport)` for the importing executable to access the DLL's public data symbols and objects.

Long story short, for functions and classes dllimport is optional, for data, for example global variables, it is mandatory